# Caller failing to hold lock before calling function std::_Mutex_base::unlock

Tags: c++, c++17, mutex

I want to create my own mutex class for usage with `std::lock_guard` etc. I have a simple implementation:

```cpp
class A
{
    std::mutex m;

public:
    void lock() {
        m.lock();
    }

    void unlock() {
        m.unlock();
    }
};
```

but when compiling with MSVC, it gives a warning `caller failing to hold lock before calling function std::_Mutex_base::unlock`. Why is that?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/KqGP1bPcW). Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I think that warning from the compiler is fair, its saying the unlock function may attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked, see: `https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/unlock/` :

> If the mutex is not currently locked by the calling thread, it causes
> undefined behavior.

Undefined behaviour is a very very bad thing so the warning is good there as if this circumstance occoured then you are in trouble.

So i don't think theres much you can do about that using std::mutex. However if you were using posix mutex theres an error code it would return which you could i guess just ignore: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock and then react to the other error codes.

> EPERM
> The current thread does not own the mutex.